# scala: updating string value in an option

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have an Option of a string. I want to update the contained value:

```
if(x.isEmpty) {
  ...another calculation
} else {
  x.map(val => ...update val)
}
```

Is this an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x.fold(another calculation)(v => ...update v)
```

e.g.

```
x.fold("no value")("Value is " + _)
```

---

Note that this **extracts** the value from the `Option` so if you want to have the result as an `Option` you need to wrap it in `Some`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if your inner computation gets too long or unreadable for a `fold`, there's always good old-fashioned pattern matching.

```scala
x match {
  case None => {
    // None case ...
  }
  case Some(y) => {
    // Some case (y is the inside) ...
  }
}
```

Like everything in Scala, this is an expression, so it can be assigned to a variable or used in another other expression you like.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using the `lazy` keyword:

```scala
// T is the type of the value
val valueOpt: Option[T] = ???
lazy val backupValue: T = ??? // Other calculation, but only evaluated if needed

val value: T = valueOpt.map( v => /*Update v*/ ).getOrElse( backupValue )
// do something with the value you want to manipulate
```